# Sortable panels, removing draggable functionality from certain elements within

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI sortable list with multiple panels within.

Unfortunately due to the draggable functionality, it's impossible to highlight/copy any text within those panels.

Therefore, I need only the header (green bar of course) of the panel to be draggable and the panel body to be excluded from this functionality.

[image: example]

Anyone have any experience with this?

Current code is out-of-box standard:

```
$('.ui-dropzone').sortable({
    connectWith: ".ui-dropzone",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [handle option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle) to define selector that can be used to drag with

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
  handle: ".handle"
});
```